# How to change a path into several lines in a .pro file of Qt?

Tags: qt

I should include a .dll file into my project which is located in a 'deep' directory, so the statement looks like this:

```
LIBS += D:\\boost_1_51_0\\bin.v2\\libs\\boost-mingw\\libs\\regex\\build\\gcc-mingw-4.7.2\\debug\\libboost_regex-mgw47-d-1_51.dll
```

It is too long to see it conveniently. How can I shorten it? I tried to cut it into two lines:

```
LIBS += D:\\boost_1_51_0\\bin.v2\\libs\\boost-mingw\\libs
\\regex\\build\\gcc-mingw-4.7.2\\debug\\libboost_regex-mgw47-d-1_51.dll
```

however, this won't compile. Here is the error message:

```
error: \regex\build\gcc-mingw-4.7.2\debug\libboost_regex-mgw47-d-1_51.dll: No such file or directory
```

So, is there any way to change the path into several lines or just shrink it?

Comment: you may use '\' at the end of line 1

Comment: @YamHon.CHAN I tried, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
LIBS += "D:/boost_1_51_0/bin.v2/libs/boost-mingw/libs/regex/build/ \
         gcc-mingw-4.7.2/debug/libboost_regex-mgw47-d-1_51.dll"
```

Comment: error: D:/boost_1_51_0/bin.v2/libs/boost-mingw/libs/regex/build/ gcc-mingw-4.7.2/debug/libboost_regex-mgw47-d-1_51.dll: No such file or directory    There is a space between '/build/' and gcc-*.

Comment: Then try:
LIBS += "D:/boost_1_51_0/bin.v2/libs/boost-mingw/libs/regex/build/\
         gcc-mingw-4.7.2/debug/libboost_regex-mgw47-d-1_51.dll"